# I want to get value from a particular cell of Excel when I enter a particular word in my word file.

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

For eg When my report in the word writes "IRR" and the corresponding value in the excel sheet for IRR is 12% then the word IRR in the Word file should be replaced by 12%.

I would be very thankful if someone can help me with the VBA code for the same

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question with your own attempts and where they are failing. SO is not a "write code for me" site.

Answer (score 1):

No need to re-invent the wheel. It's already built in.  In Word go File > Options > Proofing > Autocorrect Options and add the text and replacement value in the "Replace Text as you type" list. Then type the text and see it replaced.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your help but the problem is that it doesn't remain constant.

Comment: Like the value of the IRR depends upon the Excel file that I select. Like I have many different clients and for each client I have a excel file. I want to generate an automated report like if I paste the link of the Excel sheet then the vale of IRR should be taken from that particular Excel Sheet. I would be very thankful to you if you can guide me further.

Comment: As has been said above, this site is not a free coding service.